# Sonar 4.0 > 4.1 Upgrade: All rules deleted

Tags: sonarqube

I upgraded to Sonar 4.1 and when I ran the database update at /setup, all of my rules were removed because it thought they were deprecated. I'm fairly certain most of these are not deprecated, here is a snippet from my log:

```
2014.01.17 12:48:06 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterRules]  Removing deprecated rules
2014.01.17 12:49:22 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterRules]  Removing rule squid:UselessParenthesesCheck
2014.01.17 12:49:22 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterRules]  Removing rule squid:ObjectFinalizeCheck
2014.01.17 12:49:23 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterRules]  Removing rule squid:StringEqualityComparisonCheck
2014.01.17 12:49:25 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterRules]  Removing rule squid:UselessImportCheck
```

Fortunately I have a database backup (phew!) but **now I don't know how or if I can upgrade**. The [upgrade notes](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Release+4.1+Upgrade+Notes) don't call out anything like this. I also copied \extensions from my 4.0 installation as instructed. I've never messed with the Sonar database directly or anything like that. Did I do something wrong, or is there anything I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that the plugins of the Java Ecosystem are available in your version 4.1 package before starting the migration.

Comment: lib\bundled-plugins contains sonar-java-plugin-1.5.jar, and extensions\plugins contains sonar-java-plugin-2.0.jar copied from my 4.0 installation.

Answer (score 0):

You can bulk-add rules from the various rule catalogs by:

1. Login as an administrator and go to the `Quality  Profiles` page.
2. Select the profile you want to add all your rules to.  You'll see a page that's mostly blank with some search box stuff at the top.
3. The default filter for rules is `Active`.  Change it to `Any` and click `Search`.
4. This should list a whole lot of rules that have been deactivated.  This will also cause a little drop down box to appear in the upper right which says `Bulk Change`.  Select `Activate All` from that box.

Now you'll at least be able to get *some* analysis done while you figure out the details of your profile.